# Big-Oh proof with (n+1)!

Tags: asymptotics

Prove that $T(n) = (n+1)! + 2^n$ is $O((n+1)!)$.

Proof: by Big-Oh definition, $T(n)$ is $O((n+1)!)$ if $T(n) \leq c\cdot (n+1)!$ for some $n\geq n_0$.

Let us check this condition.  If $(n+1)! + 2^n \leq c\cdot(n+1)!$ then (this is the part I am having trouble with.  I cannot find a way to divide through the inequality to show the proof.) <= c.  Therefore, the Big-Oh condition holds for $n\geq n_0 =$ ? and $c \geq$ ?.

The question is how can I arrange the expression to be able to prove that this is $O((n+1)!)$?

Comment: $2^n \leq (n+1)!$ for $n \geq 0$

Comment: @Sil Would you mind giving a bit of clarification?

Comment: As to why it holds? You can prove that by induction, it's also clear from $2\cdot 2 \cdots 2 \leq 2 \cdot 3 \cdots (n+1)$ where there are $n$ terms on both sides.

Comment: @Sil Thank you, I used PMI.  Looks good!

Comment: You are welcome!